# Call page method after usercontrol events ends

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, parent

Hey,
How can i call a page method after a usercontol finished his method / fire a parent page method from inside the user control insted?

Comment: You need some better tags on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most elegant solution would be to have your UserControl raise an event which is handled by the parent page.

In your user control, define an event and raise it:

```
public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl {
    public event EventHandler MyMethodIsFinished;

    // ...

    protected void MyMethod {
        // ...
        if (MyMethodIsFinished != null)
            MyMethodIsFinished(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

In your page, embed the user control and define a handler:

```
<uc1:WebUserControl1 ID="MyWebUserControl1" runat="server"
                     OnMyMethodIsFinished="MyMethodIsFinishedHandler" />
```

Then write the handler code in the page:

```
protected void MyMethodIsFinishedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // do something
}
```

If you need to pass data to your event handler, the recommended way is to subclass `EventArgs`, as shown in [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkzf914z.aspx).